# What books/texts for Modern Hebrew

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, hebrew, tanach

Which of these books/texts would be possible to read when you know only Modern Hebrew?

```
Kizur Shulchan Aruch
Shulchan Aruch
Mishnah Berurah
Mishnah
Babylonian Talmud
Jerusalem Talmud

Comments by:
Rashi,
Ramban,
Rambam
```

Anything else which you can recommend for a person with Modern Hebrew knowledge?

Comment: Everything on that list except the two talmuds should be just fine.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) romario and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: What comments to Tanach by Rambam are you referring to? He didn't write a commentary on Tanach AFAIK.

Comment: @Josh K SA OC 484??

Comment: One who would like to read authoritative Torah material which is natively presented in Modern Hebrew must look towards Peninei Halakhah.

Comment: Did you mean Ramban instead of Rambam for comments on the Torah? In any case, most of these texts are very hard to understand without commentaries, the simplest of all (and not a bad idea to start) is the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch, but I recommend a text with Hebrew and commented English in parallel to make the most of it. Artscroll has a very good one (https://www.artscroll.com/Categories/kit.html).

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel I've been trying to track down the reference and I don't get it :(

Comment: @Josh K Oh ok its just an outlier siman in hilchos pesach in shulchan aruch that is was copied for some reason in its mostly aramaic form, therefore your comment is incorrect. But there are many reasons a modern hebrew speaker would have difficulty with halachic texts (or not with the talmuds..).

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel who understands 100% of the sifrei kodesh they read? Besides, there are BH many many resources available on and offline to help modern Hebrew speakers bridge the gap. The ikar is just to jump in to the texts. You are of course right that the Kitzur SA and the mishna would be easier

Comment: Tangent: Why the Qitzur Shulchan Arukh? There are other such fast guides I would recommend for someone not of Hungarian customs. (And I would definitely forewarn a modern before they get to sexual laws; his rulings for marital intimacy jar modernized sensibilities.) In Israel, where you have to deal with many Edot living together, schools often use Rav Chaim HaLevi's (Sepharadic Chief Rabbi of Tel Aviv - Yafo 1973-1998) Qitzur Shulchan Arukh Me'or Enayim. Although the author is Sepharadi, it is written with all of Israel's more common ancestries in mind.

Comment: @Josh K right, steinzaltz comes to mind!

Comment: @mbloch thanks for pointing it. I've updated the question text.

Comment: You can bridge the gap between Modern Israeli Hebrew and Biblical Hebrew with ease. I highly recommend that you read Biblical Hebrew for Students of Modern Israel Hebrew. Make sure to do the exercises. https://www.amazon.com/dp/0300084404/

Answer (score -1):

Modern Hebrew varies significantly from Biblical and Rabbinic Hebrew. Rabbinic Hebrew presupposes the reader understands the Aramaic terminology of the Babylonian Talmud. In addition, it usually contains many abbreviations and acronyms which are confusing to the uninitiated.

Rashi on Chumash should be easier, but he still uses Aramaic phrases here and there. I would recommend using Artscroll or shiurim (at least initially) to make sure you are not making mistakes.

Comment: Do you have experience reading these texts as an only-Modern Hebrew speaker? If not there's no way to know to trust you when someone could just as easily have written "Modern Hebrew varies pretty insignificantly from Biblical and Rabbinic Hebrew. There are a few extra Aramaic terms and abbreviations, but you should be fine overall." In other words, we all know the dialects are similar with differences and the only question is how those differences would affect a reader which is very hard to evaluate if you haven't been in those shoes.

Comment: @DoubleAA Not me personally, but people I know.